# integrate two merchant in paypal

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

I would like to active two merchant account In One Store  like that.
 
1: Paypal Pro  **abc@gmail.com**
2: Paypal standard  **abcd@gmail.com**
I mean i want to change Acitve both payment method same time But if user select **first** Option account should be **abc@gmail.com** and if user select **Second** option That should be select **abcd@gmail.com**